# Sort Non Ascii (UTF-8) in Gxt Grid

Tags: gwt, grid, gxt

I have simple grid like this one http://www.sencha.com/examples-2/#editablegrid;
When I add no ascii character to it (like Ł,Ć,Ź,Ż etc) after sort by column those entries go to the end instead after L or C character. How to sort by UTF-8 in grit. I am using GXT 2.2.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are sorted by UTF-8. In UTF-8 all "normal" letters stand before Ł. There is NO polish alphabet sorting defined in UTF-8.
What you need to do is write your own custom Comparator and assign it to the grid column.